# Excess Pressure Inside A Liquide Droplet

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have gone through the derivation of the following title but I have always had a doubt at one point of its derivation ,which I am going to share now.

Suppose this is the spherical droplet we are talking about and are trying to find the excess pressure off.

[image]

In this proof if the one has gone through ,you must have known that during the derivation ,people cut the sphere into 2 halves i.e 2 hemisphere and then analyze the net forces acting on one of the halves of the sphere. The forces usually are the force of liquid at the inner walls, the force due to atmospheric pressure at the outer walls of the sphere and the surface tension acting tangential to the surface of the sphere. In the below picture I will try to show you the net forces i.e after cancellation  of some components of the forces ,for all the 3 forces.
[image]

In this image I have cut a part from the sphere i.e "2"(mentioned in the first diagram) and have tried to show the net force acting around it due to the 3 forces ,you guys can try to evaluate the net forces of all the 3 forces and you will get the following result ,however I am not going to show that to you guys ,as that is not my point.

Here,the thing to keep in mind is that I have cut a part of the sphere i.e "2" and not cut it form the middle so as to get a hemisphere. Now, as the droplet is not bursting hence we can say that for the net inward force is equal to net outward force and hence by evaluating we get-:

[image]

Here "r" is the radius of the base for "2"(the part of sphere we have selected)."S" is the coefficient of surface tension of the liquid. "pie(r^2)" is the projected area for the curve surface area on which the forces are acting. "S.2(pie)r" is the force of surface tension acting at the boundaries .P(ex) is the excess pressure .And P(liq) is equal to P(atm)+ P(ex) as excess pressure means the extra outward pressure when compared with the atmospheric pressure ,thus the liquid puts P(atm) with some extra pressure i.e P(ex)

Now finally my question is, we get this same equation for excess pressure if we would have cut the droplet into two hemispheres. In place of "r" we would have got "R"(i.e the base radius of the hemisphere).This cannot be true as the pressure we are calculating should be same at every part of the sphere ,but this is concluding that for different base radius's the excess pressure change, thus how can we find the excess pressure in a droplet. Struggling with this question for past 2 days and have almost gave up on it, kindly help me with it someone.

Answer (score 1):

The total surface tension force on the spherical cap (2) is not 2. The surface tension forces, as you yourself have said, are tangential to the sphere, and at the edge of your spherical cap (2) the surface of the sphere is not going left–right. As we go round the edge, only the right-pointing components of the forces add up. The other components (those in the plane containing the cut edge) cancel. You need to include a 'cos' factor!

I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: Yes sir I have considered that and the surface tension is a tangent to the sphere ,and yes it goes left and right as you have said but I have resolved the components of it.Assuming that the surface tension is "T" then all the vertical componet of it will cancle and the horizontal componet i.e Tcos() will remain.Now all these T cos() will be along the boundary and they will add to give the surface tension along the boundary or the base of "2" which we can also write as "2 × ". The surface tension will be only along boundaries at any selected portion of the sphere,youcan checkit

Comment: As there Is so many things going on in this proof and also it is a 3d figure to analyze,thus there is a problem on my part to explain everything to the viewers.

Comment: " and they will add to give the surface tension along the boundary or the base of "2" which we can also write as "2 × "" No. $2 \pi r S \cos \theta$. And have you worked out what $\cos \theta$ is, in terms of $r$ and $R$?

Comment: Ok ok I got you ,I got you now,thank you sir....

Comment: "but how does it matter[?]" You'd then see that you get the same formula for $P_{ex}$ whether you take the small cap (2) or the hemisphere (1). I thought that you were worried by an apparent discrepancy.

Comment: Yup I got you sir,thanks